# Understanding Spark Filter Pushdown: How Does it Interact with Data Loading?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to understand how Spark optimization techniques like `filter pushdown` and `partition pruning` work in practice. Consider the following code snippet:

```
df = spark.read.csv('path', header= True, inferSchema=True)

df.filter(col('salary') > 10000)
```

My understanding is that the filter operation is be pushed down to the data source. That's whay I am reading everywhere and the same can be seen in the `physical plan` as well.

```
+- FileScan parquet [Salary#457,country_code#461] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(country_code#461), (country_code#461 = IND)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[dbfs:/FileStore/tables/bigData/withoutPartitionParquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country_code), EqualTo(country_code,IND)], ReadSchema: struct<Salary:int,country_code:string>
```

But I'm confused about how this happens. When we initially load the data using `spark.read.csv`, doesn't Spark already load the data into memory before the filter is applied? And if it's already loaded, then how is filter applied to the source?

I know that `catalyst optimizer` optimizes the query before executing, but if I just execute the **read** part first, which shows that 2 jobs (one to load data and another to inferSchema) has has run to load data into memory , then how is filter being pushed down?

Could someone please clarify how Spark handles this? I feel like I'm missing something about how Spark reads data and applies these filters.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark's read function generates the Physical plan and the filter is pushed down in the Optimized Logical plan. As you might know, the plans generated by Spark for any given job has the following stages:

`Parsed Logical Plan` -> `Analyzed Logical Plan` -> `Optimized Logical Plan` -> `Physical Logical Plan`

The **push down** occurs at the optimization stage which is done by the Catalyst optimizer. The effectiveness of certain optimizations, like predicate pushdown or partition pruning, depends on the capabilities of the data source. If the data source doesn't support these features, Spark cannot push down the filters to the data source level.

Consider the following scenarios:

**CASE 1: DATA READ FROM CSV FILE (INFERSCHEMA IS ENABLED)**

Consider the following table to be created as a dataframe `df` and note the type of the salary column is `STRING` and not `INTEGER`

| id [STRING] | name [STRING] | country_code [STRING] | salary [STRING] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bob | IND | 10000 |
| 1 | Doe | IND | 20000 |
| 2 | John | AUS | 15000 |
| 3 | Margret | AUS | 11000 |
| 4 | Bartow | USA | 10000 |
| 5 | Lisow | USA | 12000 |
| 6 | Magpipe | USA | 14000 |
| 7 | Frodo | UK | 10400 |
| 8 | Samington | UK | 10200 |
| 9 | Georgia | NZ | 23000 |

Then, applying the following filters `country_code=IND` and `salary>10000` will look as follows:

```py
df.filter((df["salary"] > 10000) & (df["country_code"] == "IND")).show()
```

The corresponding Physical Plan is as follows:

```bash
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(country_code#19) AND (country_code#19 = IND))
+- FileScan csv [id#17,name#18,country_code#19,salary#20] Batched: false, .. PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country_code), EqualTo(country_code,IND)]...
```

Here, the physical plan `PushedFilter` optimization is being applied partially only on the `country_code` column as it mentions `PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country_code), EqualTo(country_code,IND)]` in the physical plan.

**CASE 2: SCHEMA IS SPECIFIED EXPLICITLY**

Once I read the same dataframe with the `spark.read.csv` and enable the `header=True` and `schema=<CustomSchema>` defined below:

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("country_code", StringType(), True),
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)
])
```

The same filter condition now, **changes** and the **push down filter** is enabled for both the columns that are being filtered.

Spark understands for the `csv` data source with the given schema it can now push the filter down till the source read scan step and avoid unnecessary amount of data getting pulled into memory.

```py
df.filter((df["salary"] > 10000) & (df["country_code"] == "IND")).show()
```

```bash
*(1) Filter (((isnotnull(salary#97) AND isnotnull(country_code#96)) AND (salary#97 >= 10000)) AND (country_code#96 = IND))
+- FileScan csv [id#94,name#95,country_code#96,salary#97] Batched: false,
PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(salary), IsNotNull(country_code), GreaterThanOrEqual(salary,10000), EqualTo(country_code, IND)..
```

Now, the `PushedFilter` (`PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(salary), IsNotNull(country_code), GreaterThanOrEqual(salary,10000), EqualTo(country_code, IND)`) is applied on both the columns (as Spark does not have to cast the column `salary` from inferred `StringType` to an `IntegerType` since we mentioned the schema explicitly).

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you for the answer.